# How is the x-axis data determined in this chart

Tags: highcharts

I was looking at this highcharts example and I do not see any coordinates given for x-axis.

As far as i understand, a plot point should always be (x,y)

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/minrange/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'x'
    },
    xAxis: {
        minRange: 5
    },


    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series#1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no `x` value is specified, the points are assumed to be in order, and `x` values are assigned sequentially from a specified starting point.

By default, the starting point is 0.

You can specify a starting point using the `pointStart` property, and an interval using the `pointInterval` property (for instance, with a time series, you could specify a starting date, and an interval of one day, and supply an array of `y` values, and they would be plotted as one point per day, starting with the date supplied to `pointStart`)

This applies to all x axis types.

So in your example, the x values are simply 0-11, in accordance with the data array index of each point.

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointStart
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointInterval